# Laravel pp db error ( the database name is incorrect

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-artisan, mysql-error-1049

Good day this is the error i got when trying to run my laravel `php artisan serve`

The error i first got + the second error i got.

Not sure what to do?

**Error Statement:**

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'   error generated when running :127.0.0.1:8001

**Solution tried:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3630
DB_DATABASE=yourdbname
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=adminspassword
```

and

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'adminspassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `*`.`*` TO 'admin'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

**Final Error Statment:**

I got this

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'laravel'`

Comment: Did you set up your mysql server to use that non-standard port?

Comment: So your database is not called "laravel" , as set in your .env file? othewise try `php artisan optimize:clear`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not created a **database**.

So, what you need to do is:

```
sudo mysql
CREATE DATABASE yourdbname;
```

now you can start building user and permissions in the db.